# How to Circle your head in Kaparot without real money

Tags: minhag, kaparot

Every year I do Kaparot with real coins in plastic bag and after circling my head with them I donate them to Tzdaka. How can I do the Minhag of circling my head if I don't have real coins because of the COVID? I'll donate money after the Kaparot to Tzdaka, but I don't want to change the Minhag. What can I circle above my head in this situation?

Comment: I've used a check.

Comment: I usually fill out a form on the tzedaka's website on my phone, then circle the phone over my head, then push submit.  I prefer that (or a check, as @NT suggested) to coins because the tzedaka can be a substantial amount this way and not just symbolic.

Comment: Do it with something that is worth a certain amount of money, e.g. a ring, and then redeem the ring for money afterwards.

Comment: What about paper bills?

Comment: You could always get a live chicken ;)